# undefined reference to function and ld returned 1 exit status error. There are no syntax error.

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I know this question has been asked many times and I have tried all solutions that have been posted but for me, it seems it doesn't work. I don't know if it is compiler problem or I am doing it the wrong way.

I am fetching data from a 'bin.txt' file that I created. It contains 3x3 matrix of 0 and 1 (without any space between two digits) only. I want to count how many zeros and ones are there and according to that, I want to make a new text file (in my code 'encode.txt') and write those counted digits into that file.

I am using GNU GCC compiler on CodeBlocks. Here is my code and if you find typos then I am really sorry. I don't mean to waste your time on that. Any help and tips on this are appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define row 3
#define col 3

int foo(int x, int y);

int main()
 {
   FILE *ptr;
   FILE *encode;
   int i,j,zero=0,one=0;
   int a[row][col];
   ptr=fopen("bin.txt","r");
   encode = fopen("encode.txt","w");

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        fscanf(ptr,"%1d",&a[i][j]);
        if(a[i][j]==0)
        {
            zero++;
        }
        else
        {
            one++;
        }
    }
    foo(zero, one);
    zero=0;
    one=0;
}

/*----------------Print scaned file----------------------------------*/
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        printf("%1d",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
/*----------- Foo function ----------*/

int foo(int x, int y)
 {
   fprintf(encode,"%d %d",x,y);
   fprintf(encode,"\n");
 }

/*----------- Closing file ----------*/
  fclose(ptr);
  fclose(encode);

  return 0;
  }
```

Build Log:

```
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\file_compress.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
E:/Code/C/File compression/file_compress/main.c:31: undefined reference to 
`foo'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: You can't define a function inside another function. Move the definition of `foo` outside of `main`

Comment: ahh, my bad I didn't notice that. Thanks For your help

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! If that is C code, use a C compiler, i.e. the gcc frontend, not the C++ frontend g++! Otherwise change the tag. And read the gcc man-page.

Comment: @Arkia: The fierce thing is gcc allows this as an extension (enabled by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested functions are not allowed in standard C (though GCC provides an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)). You probably didn't intend to use a nested function anyway; move the definition of `foo()` function outside `main()` function.